# POO Encapsulamiento C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de modularidad en el cual quiero poner en forma practica la encapsulación de datos y métodos.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

namespace Modularidad {

    class Program {

        static void Main(string[] args) {


            Modulo modulo = new Modulo(); 
            double resp = modulo.suma(3.5, 2.7); 
            Console.WriteLine("La suma es: " + resp); 
            Console.WriteLine(""); 

            Modulo1 modulo1 = new Modulo1(); 
            double pro = modulo1.multiplicacion(5.2, 8.3); 
            Console.WriteLine("La multiplicacion es: " + pro); 
            Console.WriteLine(""); 

            Modulo2 Modulo2 = new Modulo2(); 
            double resta = Modulo2.restar(4.3, 5.2); 
            Console.WriteLine("La resta es: " + resta); 
            Console.WriteLine(""); 

            Modulo3 Modulo3 = new Modulo3(); 
            double division = Modulo3.dividir(25, 5); 
            Console.WriteLine("La division es: " + division); 
            Console.WriteLine(""); 

            persona persona = new persona(); 
            string nombre = persona.nombre("Sasori"); 
            Console.WriteLine("El nombre del usuario es: " + nombre); 
            Console.ReadKey(); 
        }
    }


    class Modulo {

        public double suma(double n1, double n2) {
            double resultado = 0; 
            resultado = n1 + n2; 
            return resultado; 
        }
    }

    class Modulo1 {

        public double multiplicacion (double n1, double n2) {
            double producto = 0; 
            producto = n1 * n2; 
            return producto; 
        }
    }

    class Modulo2 {
        public double restar(double n1, double n2) {
            double resultado = 0; 
            resultado = n1 - n2; 
            return resultado; 
        }
    }

    class Modulo3 {
        public double dividir(double n1, double n2) {
            double division = 0; 
            division = n1 / n2; 
            return division; 
        }
     }

    class persona {
        public string nombre(string entrada) {
            string nombre; 
            nombre = entrada; 
            return entrada; 
        }
    }
}
```

Mi duda es: ¿Cómo implemento el encapsulamiento a los campos(objetos) a mi ejemplo?

Se que puedo usar los tres niveles de acceso `(public, private y protected)` en el caso de la vista "public" si un método posee este tipo de vista, se puede mandar a llamar desde cualquier otra clase al método indicado.

Lo que aún no he entendido es

> ¿Cómo acceder a un objeto con un tipo de vista "private" o "protected"?

ya que no se puede acceder al objeto directamente ya que (en el caso de "private) el objeto solo puede interactuar dentro de la propia clase.

Investigando un poco se utilizan propiedades para los campos en los cuales se utilizan "get" y "set" para asignar y obtener valores, pero quisiera poder aplicar todo esto a mi ejemplo ya que no he entendido en su totalidad la funcionalidad y aplicación del encapsulamiento

Comment: 2 cosas: en esta imagen te da la idea general https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFysv.jpg segundo, en este enlace está la documentación, te sugiero leerla: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers Entre más pronto le agarres el gusto a la documentación, te dará la libertad de aprender cualquier cosa. Te lo digo en buen plan :) Saludos y buena suerte con la lectura :D

Comment: En C# el encapsulamiento de los datos se hace principalmente via propiedades, que son muy cómodas para trabajar. Básicamente, se definen los campos como privados, y luego se crea una propiedad publica (o protegida) que es la que realmente da acceso a los datos. De todas maneras, en tu ejemplo no aplica ya que los modulos no tienen ningun campo que pueda ser privado, solo métodos que devuelven valores.